# when .trx file is created in Coded UI Test

Tags: tfs

I am running a script through visual studio 2015 and checking for .trx file in test results folder.But I found the folder empty.

Can someone tell me when .trx file created.Only for Ordered Test or for both orderedtest and script running.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, .trx file can be only created with running the test in command line. Script running can not generate the .trx file.

**VSTest**:
 To log results into a Visual Studio Test Results File (TRX) you can use the option `/Logger:trx`. See [VSTest.Console.exe command-line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) options for details.

**MSTest** :  You can use the option `/resultsfile:[ file name ]` to save the test run results to the specified file.

Example: `/resultsfile:testResults.trx`

See [MSTest.exe command-line options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) for details.